# Loading multiple models with loadModel promise

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I would like to load an array of models using loadModel promise and loadAsHidden option. Then once all the models are loaded show them all at once. It seems every promise is resolved straight after I run the loadModel command. So the showHiddenModels function is ran before the models are fully loaded. Storeys array contains the svf addresses of the files.

```
function loadAllModels() {
    let options =
    {
        loadAsHidden: true,
        globalOffset: { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 }            
    };

    let promises = [];
    let length = storeys.length;
    let counter = 0;

    for (let storey of storeys) {
        let modelPromise = viewer.loadModel(storey.Svf, options);
        modelPromise.then((result) => {                
            counter++;
            console.log('counter: ' + counter);

            if (counter == length) {
                showHiddenModels();
            }
        });

        promises.push(modelPromise);
    }
}

function showHiddenModels() {
    let models = viewer.impl.modelQueue().getHiddenModels();

    for (let model of models) {
         viewer.showModel(model);
    }

    let extension = viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.ViewCubeUi');
    extension.setViewCube('[top/front]');     
}
```

This is how it looks in the console. So first the promise.then is called and after that it starts loading the files.

[image: Console]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LoadModel` fulfills its promise soon as the model seed file is loaded and not its full geometry/texture etc...

For lifecycle event where the model is completed loaded subscribe to `Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT`:

```
viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT, event=>{
  //event {type:string, model:object, target:object}
})
```

And in multiple model scenarios this event would fire multiple times when each and every model finishes loading - use the id of the `model` object to tell when the last model is completely loaded.